# Run an exe in ASCX with its arguments in Ektron

Tags: c#, cmd, ascx, ektron, windows-task-scheduler

I want to add a scheduled task to the windows task scheduler with the help of schtasks.exe in system32 folder.

I did it as following in aspx.cs pages:

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/create /tn mylbat /tr MYLExe.exe /sc daily /st " + txthh.Text + ":" + txtmm.Text;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

But the same is not working in an ascx.cs file. Is there any parameter that I need to set in the Process object?

**Edit I:**

The same ascx is workin in a normal asp site but its not workin in an Ektron site.
I want to add it as a widget in the smart desktop of Ektron 8.0 too.

**The site is hosted in IIS.**

What should be the parameters of the Process and the exe SCHTASKS.exe when the site is run on IIS

Comment: What are the differences in environment, system setup etc... when you are running this code in the ascx and the aspx files?

Comment: What means "not working"? Is it throwing an exception? Do you see something in your debugger?

Comment: @rhughes: its the same environment

Comment: @Grumbler85: No its just not adding the task to the queue, wen i run the command "schtasks /query /tn mylbat" it shows no such task. I tried the debugger too, but no exception's being caught.

Comment: @AJ so the same page, same everything, just the code is in the ascx, rather than in the aspx? If so, what is the error you getting when the code is in the ascx? Are you 100% sure the ascx code is running?

Comment: @rhughes: yes I am. But its not the same page. Have you heard of Ektron (a cms). I need to add it into the controls of ektron.But that makes no difference. I tried running it step by step too..but just cant figure out the issue

Comment: @AJ what are the differences between the two pages? I'm sorry, I don't know much about Ektron, but it must be something with how the pages are managed. Does it work if you put the ASCX in the ASPX page that you know does work?

Comment: Sorry this ascx is workin in a simple asp.net site and not in Ektron site. There must be some dependancy then.I shall edit the post and also look for the same myself.Must be an ektron issue